# Can't get the value from Email Input

Tags: javascript, html

I've downloaded a template form to sign in with bootstrap. When I try to get the value from the email or password field nothing happens.

the from looks like this

```
   <form class="form-signin">
            <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button onclick="autentica()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

and the function I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
<script>
    function autentica(){
    var mail = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value();
    alert(mail);
    if(document.getElementById("inputEmail").value() == "admin@admin.cl" && document.getElementById("inputPassword").value() == "admin"){
        document.location.href= "dashboard.html";
  }
}
</script>
```

Neither the alert nor the changing page works.
The "dashboard.html" file is on the same folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use value as function call. Remove the round brackets.

Comment: `nothing happens` is not exactly true, the console logs an error: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value is not a function` (also, anybody can look at the source and find out the login/password)

Comment: I'm just trying to change the page if the login/pass matches, I'va removed the round brackets but still cant change the page. Is the ```document.location.href= "dashboard.html";``` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function `value()`, but it's a (string) property `value`. So the correct syntax would be: `var mail = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;`

Comment: Now the alert works, thanks for that. There is just one problem left: how do I change the page? the code is not working. Is there an "Equals()" function on javascript?